# Why extraspace in the last column?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I'm trying to make a simple table but a strange space appears in the last column and I don't know why.

[image]

I share the used code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|}
            \cline{2-5}
            \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{-20-Distribución basada en satisfacción proporcional}} \\ \cline{2-5} 
            \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \textbf{0\%} & \textbf{0,25\%} & \textbf{0,5\%} & \textbf{0,75\%} \\ \hline 
            \multicolumn{1}{|c||}{\textbf{Min.}} &  19998  &  20288  &  21648  &  20406  \\ \hline  
            \multicolumn{1}{|c||}{\textbf{1st Qu.}} &  23522  &  24134.25  &  23088.5  &  23121  \\ \hline  
            \multicolumn{1}{|c||}{\textbf{Median}} &  24356  &  \textbf{*26264.5}  &  24452  &  24256  \\ \hline  
            \multicolumn{1}{|c||}{\textbf{Mean}} &  24171.8  &  25352.05  &  24849.55  &  24746.75  \\ \hline  
            \multicolumn{1}{|c||}{\textbf{3rd Qu.}} &  25158.5  &  26730.75  &  26959.75  &  26931.75  \\ \hline  
            \multicolumn{1}{|c||}{\textbf{Max.}} &  26564  &  28785  &  29683  &  27433  \\ \hline  
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why? Simple: your multicolumn cell is too wide.

Comment: you have used a `c` column: `\multicolumn{4}{c|}` `c` columns are like `\mbox`  are as wide as their content, on a single line.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative format:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,booktabs,siunitx}
\sisetup{input-decimal-markers={.},group-separator={\,}}
\sisetup{table-space-text-post ={\bfseries\,***}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering\tabcolsep0pt
\begin{tabular}{@{}l
S[table-format=8.0] %modify as need 
S[table-format=7.0,table-align-text-post=false]
S[table-format=9.1]
S[table-format=7.0]
@{}}\toprule
 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\bfseries 20 -- Distribución basada en satisfacción proporcional} \\\cmidrule{2-5} 
 &\SI{0}{\percent} & \SI{0.25}{\percent} & \SI{0.50}{\percent} & \SI{0.75}{\percent} \\\midrule  
 Min. &  19998  &  20288  &  21648  &  20406  \\   
 1st Qu. &  23522  &  24134.25  &  23088.5  &  23121  \\   
 Median &  24356  &  26264.5{\bfseries\,***}  &  24452  &  24256  \\   
 Mean &  24171.8  &  25352.05  &  24849.55  &  24746.75  \\   
 3rd Qu. &  25158.5  &  26730.75  &  26959.75  &  26931.75  \\   
 Max. &  26564  &  28785  &  29683  &  27433  \\\bottomrule  
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

BTW, do you really need a precision of two decimals for numbers of five digits? Moreover, only for some? Even with a decimal align, the columns look misaligned and then otherwise trivial tasks, as center a header or add some asterik, become much more complex due of the S columns.

Comment: It is more than enough, true that the precision of two decimals is not very useful, your first answer before edit helped me, really like this table style. Thank you.